# Mediawiki search form autocomplete not working on my custom skin

Tags: mediawiki, skinning

Hello gurus of Mediawiki,

I am having trouble with modifying one of my custom mediawiki skin (1.26).
I followed the mediawiki [skinning guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_2) to create a search form within my BaseTemplate. I am using the provided API method makeSearchInput to create the search input box. But for some reason, its not doing the auto-complete as it is supposed to do. I have looked into other mediawiki skin examples, tried to duplicate the settings to see if I can get it to work, but nothing really helped.

```
 <form class="mw-search" role="form" id="searchform" action="<?php $this->text('wgScript'); ?>">
            <?php
              echo $this->makeSearchInput(array('id' => 'searchInput'));

              echo Html::hidden( 'title', $this->get( 'searchtitle' ) );
             ?>
 </form>
```

When I look into the network activity, all of the other skins where the autocomplete works, I can see the network connectivity sending commands to the api.php each time I input any character into the input box. But for some reason, it doesn't send anything on my own custom skin. It almost looks like it doesn't even attempt to send the query. I have been searching online but without any luck in discovering what the problem is. Since it works on the other skins on the same server, it's probably not the global settings that I am missing but it could be something that I missed on skin configuration. I am not trying to do any fancy modification, so I must be doing something silly. I have been struggling and wasting many hours on this, so now I am here asking for the help...

Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing this?
Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Sincerely,

Comment: Do you have a bit more code than that maybe? If your skin is publicly available, that might help a lot. Also are there any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess that you are not calling `$this->printTrail();` at the end of the `<body>` tag inside the class that extends class BaseTemplate.

Also you are not closing the body and html elements.

Comment: @FO-nTTaX  Ah, you are right. It was missing the $this -> printTrail(). Adding that resolved everything.. Thank you so much!